# What does the $4$ mean in the output of sha1pass?

Tags: passwords, sha1

When creating a password with `sha1pass`, the first value from the token, is '4'.

For instance:

```
sha1pass test
```

gives us:

```
$4$GTdnmykS$25iwV+ruXRwor4pUmKF57uXHj70$
```

The token uses `$` as separators: `25iwV+ruXRwor4pUmKF57uXHj70` is the computed hash, `GTdnmykS` is the generated salt, since I didn't supply a second parameter, but what does that `4` mean?

The 4 is actually hardcoded, this is the last line of `sha1pass`, which is a Perl script:

```
print '$4$', $salt, '$', $pass, "\$\n";
```

Why is the first value of that token '4', and what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen the convention used where $1$ denotes MD5 and $4$ denotes SHA1.  It's hardcoded because it's simply encoding how the hash was generated for future comparison.

Answer (score 8):

It's just a signature so you know what you're looking at is a SHA-1 password; `$1$` is used for MD5, `$5$` for SHA-2-256, and `$6$` for SHA-2-512.

Answer (score 3):

It's a signature telling you the hash type is used, that much is *obvious*.

Now, **why** is is present? It's because it's used for unix password hashes, check [crypt (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)#Library_Function):

> If the salt begins with the string **$digit$** then the Modular Crypt Format is used. The digit represents which algorithm is used in encryption.